# ImageOps.fit() with transparent parts in ICO images

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, alpha

I have a source file `image.ico` of any size and want to create a thumbnail. This is the code i am using right now:

```
    converted_file = cStringIO.StringIO()
    thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, (width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    thumb.save(converted_file, format='png')
```

I chose `png` as extension because PIL does not support `ico` files which could be the culprit. It works beside the fact that transparency is not applied. Parts with alpha=0 are rendered black instead of being transparent. How can i fix this behavior?

**/edit**

I also tried ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1386382/675065)):

```
    converted_file = cStringIO.StringIO()
    thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, (width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    background = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (255, 255, 255, 0))
    background.paste(thumb, box = (0, 0, width, height))
    background.save(converted_file, format='png')
```

Same effect.

Comment: How are you looking at the image? Try opening it in Chrome for example. Do the transparent areas still appear to be black?

Comment: yes. this answer may be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987916/how-to-determine-the-transparent-color-index-of-ico-image-with-pil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is indeed that PIL does not know how to exactly read ICO files. There are two possibilities how to fix this:

1. Add a plugin to PIL that registers the ICO format
2. Use Pillow, a fork of PIL that is more frequently updated

I chose to use Pillow which is also Python 3 compatible and has some more goodies.

### 1. PIL Plugin

Save the [Win32IconImagePlugin](https://code.google.com/p/casadebender/wiki/Win32IconImagePlugin) somewhere in your project. After importing the PIL Image class, import the plugin to register ICO support:

```
from PIL import Image
import Win32IconImagePlugin
```

There you go, now you can use the right format:

```
thumb.save(converted_file, format='ico')
```

### 2. Pillow

**[Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0)** has [builtin support for ICO images](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py).

Just remove pil and install pillow:

```
pip uninstall pil
pip install pillow
```

Be sure to change all global pil imports:

```
import Image, ImageOps
```

to

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
```

There you go, now you can use the right format:

```
thumb.save(converted_file, format='ico')
```